# PhpStorm tables displaying database setting

Tags: database-connection, phpstorm, sap-iq

I connect to Sybase IQ database via PhpStorm. End I have a tables explorer at `database tool window`.

What I need is to make tables names display like `schema_name.table_name`, not just the table name. Seems like I can achieve it in database driver settings, but don't know what should I do exactly. There is a setting in database connection window where I can choose such setting in AquaData studio.

Comment: SAP Sybase IQ is not having something like schema. It's user.tablename at level with most verbosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to have `schema_name.table_name` -- only `db_name.schema_name.table_name`.

For this just enable **"Flatten Schemas" option** (under "cog" icon or via right click on tool window title/label).

**P.S.**
Cannot say anything about database driver settings for Sybase.